# "May not respond to " Warrning

Tags: iphone, ios

'Treatment' May not respond to '+findAllTreatments'  warning show at the below coding

```
_rootViewController.treatments = [Treatment findAllTreatments];
```

What should be the reason.

Comment: Check your Treatment.h file, it seems the function findAllTreatments is not defined.

Comment: Please post some code of your Treatment object (.h and .m). In its current state, your question is unanswerable..

Comment: App is working properly. findAllTreatments  function is defined. But warnings are shown in xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `+ (void)findAllTreatments;` in Treatment.h (or .h file where Treatment class declared). Don't forget that it is class method, not instance method.

Comment: Wrong declaration cased the problem.I declared findAllTreatments as static method.Even though It works with warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Treatment` does not declare a static method `findAllTreatments` in its interface.